# Android support lib v4 or v13

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have developed an Android application build using API 13 and min-sdk also API 13. I want to incorporate the swiping across the tabs, and for the purpose I am using [v4 support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

I have following questions,

1. Which support library I should use v4 or v13?
2. Should I change the target to API 14? More importantly how do I decide, which should be my targeted API to compile against?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Support Package / Compatibility Library - use v4 or v13?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926403/android-support-package-compatibility-library-use-v4-or-v13)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For question 1:
as @StinePike said, depending on what you use as minimum, you should use v4 for min-sdk = 4-12 if your min sdk is >=13 its ok to use v13.
**Update** As stated by Frank in the comments, with revision 26.0.0 and above the minsdk for all support libraries is API level 14. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions for more details.

For question 2: the best target depends on what you plan to do, if you want to provide some features that were introduced in a higher sdk level, you have to use higher target-sdk but make sure that you check the android version to not use android apis that are introduced in a higer sdk version on a device with an older android version

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // safe to use api 11 / Android 3.0 stuf
} else {
    // only use api level <= 10 stuff
}
```

for min-sdk its the same. if you require stuff of api level >= 10 you have to use min-sdk 10

<strike>*My opinion: don't use api level < 10, its not worth it... with 10 you reach 90% of the android devices*</strike>
*My opinion (as of April 2016): don't use api level < 16, its not worth it... with 16 you reach ~95% of the android devices*

For checking the distribution of android OS version check: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: If you unzip v13 I noticed v4+v13 is in the same jar. Does that mean you can use v13 from API4 and up? Or?

Comment: v13 contains some classes, that are not available on API < 13. so if you want to target an api < 13 you have to use v4.

Comment: Starting with Support Library version 26.0.0, the minimum supported API level has changed to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for ALL support library packages. source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions

Answer (score 10):

from the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) you can find

> Note: The Support Package includes more than one support library. Each
>   one has a different minimum API level. For example, one library
>   requires API level 4 or higher, while another requires API level 13 or
>   higher (v13 is a superset of v4 and includes additional support
>   classes to work with v13 APIs). The minimum version is indicated by
>   the directory name, such as v4/ and v13/.

I think that clearly answer your question. If you want to support lower os version ( 4 or higher) and the v4 library apis fullfill your target then use it else use v13

Comment: Can you provide the link to your reference?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My other question, how do I decide my target-sdk ?

Comment: It is depending on your application need. if your need fullfilled by v4 then use 4 else if you use v13 use 13

Comment: If you unzip v13 I noticed v4+v13 is in the same jar. Does that mean you can use v13 from API4 and up? Or?

Answer (score 0):

As android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7 is 23.6 percents in [martet](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform) now, I suggest seting minSdk = 10 for these devices especially google has provided a good solution for developers to practice better  by using support v4 and v7.

To your question, [a detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173951/1251276) which I've posted may help.